# Why can std::wcout not output all UCS-2 characters?

Tags: c++, unicode, character-encoding, locale, iostream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wcout.imbue(/* What to place here? */);

    for (wchar_t c = 0; c <= 0xFFFF; c++)
    {
        if (IsHumanReadable(c))
        {
            wcout << c; // c may be a Chinese or Arabic character.
        }
    }
}
```

My machine is Windows 7, which is unicode-based.

The code above doesn't output any Arabic characters, whereas the same character can be showed correctly in the source file, which proves my machine supports displaying Arabic characters.

Why can Arabic characters not displayed in the console window?

Comment: *"How to make it work as expected?"* .. Apart from the obvious (it works) what are your specific expectations? A large number of the values you're trying to emit are not even valid codepoints. are you expecting those to work as well?

Comment: i.e. outputing all human readable characters.

Comment: And how is the code above failing to meet your expectations?

Comment: @Praetorian, for (wchar_t c = 0; c <= 0xFFFF; c++)
    {
        if (IsHumanReadable(c))
        {
            wcout << c;
        }
    }

Comment: if that is the case, you may want ot [read up on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) in general, and specifically locale settings and valid code-points for said same. What you're trying to do is not as trivial as it may seem.

Comment: Where is the output going? How are you checking the result? Perhaps the limitation is there? Do you have a font with all "human readable" characters represented?

Comment: @Bo, my os is Windows, which is unicode-based.

Comment: @user1587418, I assume surrogate pairs are filtered by the function IsHumanReadable. i.e. I treat those as not human readable.

Answer (score 0):

The first line should be

```
 _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);
```

which is the Windows equivalent of the appropriate imbue() for wide character output (they still don't support Unicode in standard C++ except for what C++11 made a requirement).

Check MSDN for the headers to #include

Also note that the font installed in console window often lacks much of other Windows programs can display. When in doubt, redirect program output to a file and open that file with Wordpad etc.